# Dual extruder setup in Marlin

Tags: dual-nozzle

I have a Tevo Tarantula with a MKS Base 1.5 board and dual extruders.  I am running Marlin RC8 Tevo Community build for the dual extruder, large bed and SN04 sensor.

All temperature sensors work and give accurate reading but `E1` when activated runs at 100% until the overtemps kicks in and shuts down the system.  Like I said, it reads proper temperatures through the thermistor it just won’t stop at the set temperature.  I checked the MOSFET and there is no obvious scorching or bad solder joints on the MKS board.  This leads me to believe it is a mix-up in firmware but, being a bit of a newbie on this, I am still getting familiar with G-code and Marlin.

I have confirmed the correct board is being referenced in firmware from `boards.h` but looking at `configuration.h` I just get confused.  What I am thinking is somehow/somewhere `E1` might be referenced as a fan that is just off or on.  Anybody have ideas?

Comment: Is [this build](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula) what you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the hardware config is for the **Tevo Tarantula**

Make sure your `configuration.h` file is setup for your hardware.
The extruder defines are describe in [Conditional_LCD.h](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/Conditionals_LCD.h)

It looks like the [configuration.h file](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h) on GitHub is configured for a single extruder.

For example, if you have 2 hotends; but, "HOTENDS=2" is not set then the I/O will not be configured for the 2nd hotend.  I just looked at the code and if `HOTENDS == 1` then the `MOSFET_D_PIN` will be used to control FAN1 (which sounds very similar to what you are describing that you are seeing).

```
  #if HOTENDS == 1
    #define FAN1_PIN     MOSFET_D_PIN
  #else
    #define HEATER_1_PIN MOSFET_D_PIN
  #endif
```

Comment: If the tarantula uses a single hotend, don't define SINGLENOZZLE but define SWITCHING_EXTRUDER and (i think) EXTRUDERS=2.  Then the code will expect the single hotend to be connected to D10.

Comment: Thank you for the direction to go. The setup is dual and I "thought" I had checked that.

Comment: "Dual" can mean several things.  Do you have two separate extruders (hotends), a (single) mixing extruder, or a (single) standard extruder with a dual filament feeder?  Marlin has to be configured for the specific type.

Answer (score 0):

So, following on from [Mark's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4177/dual-extruder-setup-in-marlin/4179#4179), in [line 298](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/Conditionals_LCD.h#L298) of [Conditional_LCD.h](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/Conditionals_LCD.h), you would need to change:

```
#define HOTENDS       1
```

to

```
#define HOTENDS       2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my documentation was wrong and the heater & thermistor were wired in backwards. Maybe recheck your wiring and even try reversing the temp sensor on your board.

Comment: Do you mean that you swapped the heater and thermistor connections, or do you mean that the thermistor was connected to the right therminals - but backwards? Thermistors and heaters are generally not polarized, and can be connected either way around. They're just simple resistors.